# Загрузил сайт на хостинг, при загрузке белый экран

Tags: хостинг

Вот собственно сайт: http://grillmer.com .
Есть идеё в чём собственно проблема может быть?

Comment: А что за хостинг, на чём сайт - нам самим догадаться?

Comment: Вы можете загрузить файл типа index.html, а в нем написать рыбный текст. Далее попробовать его открыть, например http://grillmer.com/index.html. Если у вас пустая папка с сайтом а файл index.html загрузили и ничего не происходит, то обратите внимание на ответ, возможно у Вас действительно ещё не обновились DNS

Comment: https://ukrline.com.ua/ хостинг

Answer (score 2):

Этот адрес у меня не пингуется, может надо потерпеть денёк?

```
traceroute to grillmer.com (50.63.202.53), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router (192.168.88.1)  0.261 ms  0.288 ms  0.317 ms
 2  ***.***.***.*** (***.***.***.***)  4.304 ms  4.305 ms  4.320 ms
 3  91.205.217.250 (91.205.217.250)  4.257 ms  4.238 ms  4.214 ms
 4  91.205.216.1 (91.205.216.1)  5.387 ms  5.401 ms  5.400 ms
 5  ip26-131-200-109.crelcom.ru (109.200.131.26)  4.260 ms  4.281 ms  4.305 ms
 6  ae36-0.smfl-04-cr1.miranda-media.net (178.34.177.189)  4.988 ms  4.723 ms  4.693 ms
 7  87.226.221.10 (87.226.221.10)  42.250 ms  59.457 ms  42.390 ms
 8  213.59.211.237 (213.59.211.237)  42.317 ms  43.245 ms 213.59.212.217 (213.59.212.217)  43.172 ms
 9  rostelecom-ic-319651-ffm-b1.c.telia.net (62.115.151.97)  73.939 ms  74.018 ms  73.989 ms
10  ffm-b1-link.telia.net (62.115.151.96)  103.613 ms  103.612 ms  111.228 ms
11  * * *
12  ae-2-30.bear2.phoenix1.level3.net (4.69.210.161)  224.927 ms  225.009 ms *
13  4.28.83.74 (4.28.83.74)  235.972 ms  235.990 ms  235.971 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: Может быть вы правы, вчера в 19:47 залил файлы. Я читал, что около дня там идёт обработка или что-то вроде этого.